# Caliburn Micro Datagrid Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

My items from context menu are not executing.
My xaml:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:arFirmaKomp.Views"
         xmlns:arFirmaKomp="clr-namespace:arFirmaKomp" x:Class="arFirmaKomp.Views.ArKlienciView"
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:arFirmaKomp.ViewHelpers"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="600" Width="1200" >
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ArKlienciList" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=WybranyArKlient, Mode=OneWayToSource}" DisplayMemberPath="PodmiotyOdbiorcaNazwaSkrocona" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Height="22" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="ArKlienciList2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ArKlienciICView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event CellEditEnding]=[Action SaveChanges()];[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action RowSelect()]"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="17,80,10,20" EnableRowVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding}" IsOpen="{Binding Data.IsContextMenuOpen, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" 
                          cal:Message.Attach="Open($dataContext)">
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nexoKlientNabywcaColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Nexo Klient Nabywca" Binding="{Binding PodmiotyNabywcaNazwaSkrocona,Mode=OneWay}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nexoKlientOdbiorcaColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Nexo Klient Odbiorca" Binding="{Binding PodmiotyOdbiorcaNazwaSkrocona,Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nexoKlientOdbiorcaTelefonColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Nexo Odbiorca Telefon" Binding="{Binding OdbiorcaTelefon,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>


        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="FilterString" Height="19" Margin="128,15,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134"/>
    <Label Content="filtr odbiorca" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="17,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>


</Grid>
```

My viewmodel - contextmenu part:

```
    public void Open(object source)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)source);
    }
```

My bindingProxy is taken from [Thomas Levesque Blog](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

I can see this context menu, and as I saw in other similar posts context menu is not connected with my ViewModel, and I don't know how to connect it. Contextmenu should make some action with the selected row as a parameter.